# DNS server in Ubuntu (assign a static IP address to a parked domain)

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, domain

How to configure DNS server in Ubuntu?

I have a static IP address that needs to be assigned to a parked domain.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your problem but if you want to point a dns entry to your machine you don't need your own dns server. You can do that using the control panel where you bought the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local domain, in your LAN, you can just edit /etc/hosts, add the IP and domain.

If it's a public domain, and the nameservers are set to your provider, you just need to "tell" the nameservers point to your (public) IP address.

Comment: Sorry to post to a rather old post. I didn't realize.